# Swift 4 StreamDelegate not being called

Tags: swift, inputstream, gamekit

I've been working on create a connection with my server and have gotten it to connect. However the stream delegate is not being called. I am setting the stream delegate to self, have tried messing around with the .schedule,,using .unretainedvalue as well as .retainedvalue,, casted and not casted to InputStream/OutputStream.. Heres my fun connect()

```
var inputOpened = false
var outputOpened = false
var state: NetworkState?
var inputStream: InputStream!
var outputStream: OutputStream!
func connect() {
    state = NetworkState.NetworkStateConnectingToServer
    var readStream:  Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
    var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil, "192.168.1.4" as CFString, 1955, &readStream, &writeStream)

    inputStream = readStream?.takeRetainedValue() as! InputStream!
    outputStream = writeStream?.takeUnretainedValue() as! OutputStream!
    inputStream.delegate = self
    outputStream.delegate = self
    inputStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
    outputStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
    inputStream.open()
    outputStream.open()
}
```

and my stream delegate function

```
 func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
    print("ran")
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        if aStream == self.inputStream {
            self.inputStreamHandle(eventCode)
        }
        else if aStream == self.outputStream {
            self.outputStreamHandle(eventCode)
        }

    })
}
```